# Should I hide fb:app_id from users?

Tags: facebook, app-id

I recently implemented the new open graph 3.x in my ios app. It's awesome, what a huge upgrade. My only concern is that now when a user clicks on the post on facebook they can see the graph objects URL (og:url) which includes my fb:app_id.

For example:
http://www.myhostingwebsite.com/mygraphobject.php?fb%3Aapp_id%[My Facebook app id]%26og%253A [... The rest of the URL ..]

Is this normal? Or am I doing something wrong? If users have this id is there any harm that can be done?

Answer (score 3):

This is normal. You need app secret to do anything as your app, so as long as you keep that a secret everything should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

- Depends on you,app_id can be shown or don't show it
- but app secret cannot , it can let others use for other purpose
- and be careful access token